# OpenCV compare faces with small resolution images | Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, face-recognition

**Step 1.** Detect faces in an image, crop the faces, and save them.

Image shape: `[1000, 970, 3]`

**Step 2.** Compare the smaller cropped images with the original image and see if enough matches are found, and whether they are the correct matches. (Eye to eye, not eye to tree)

Image Shape: `[60, 60, 3]`

Step 1 works fine.

Step 2 recognizes many matches, but they are too obscure to be of any use since you can't really trust that result.

Here's a subset of the code I am using for Step 1:

```
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        count += 1
        crop_img = image[y:y + w, x:x + h]
        r = 200 / crop_img.shape[1]
        dim = (200, int(crop_img.shape[0] * r))
        crop_img = cv2.resize(crop_img, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        cv2.imwrite('images/college/' + str(count) + '.jpg', crop_img)
```

And here's how I compare the images:

```
img1 = cv2.imread(testImage)
img2 = cv2.imread('images/Class-of-2018.jpg')
# plt.imshow(img2), plt.show()

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 100

orb = cv2.ORB_create()

kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

good = bf.match(des1, des2)

good = sorted(good, key=lambda x: x.distance)
```

Additional code is used to show which parts of the image have a match, and if that is needed, I can post that.

I'd like to know if this is the correct approach to such a problem. Or is there a better way? Maybe I have to train a classifier(**FaceRecognizer**) for every person in the image? If yes, how should I do that?

Comment: with that much difference in image sizes, ORB won't be good enough with its default parameters. May be you can change the parameters for the detector/descriptor or both since ORB is not completely scale invariant.

Comment: Let me try that.

Comment: @RickM. Thanks. Is there a way to succesfully predict/select MIN_MATCH_COUNT?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by MIN_MATCH_COUNT? Can you elaborate?

Comment: What I mean is, since the script runs in the background with no human actually looking at the results, what should be the threshold number of matches found before it is declared that the face exists(is of the same person)?

Comment: I guess you have to figure that out yourself since it is just about the matches and you don't compute the homography. You could sort the matches and take first 20 for example but it completely depends on the _extent of goodness_ of these matches.

Comment: make the same size of both image than compare feature it works

Comment: Don't you think the main image would lose a lot of quality if I try to significantly decrease its size?